# Running the project by build is not working in MAC OSX 10.7

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, artwork, avmetadataitem

```
-(void)artworkImages{
NSArray *noOfSongs = [mySongsArray content];
for (int i=0; i<[noOfSongs count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    dic = [[mySongsArray arrangedObjects] objectAtIndex:i];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[dic objectForKey:@"Path"]];
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
   for (NSString *format in [asset availableMetadataFormats]) {
        for (AVMetadataItem *item in [asset metadataForFormat:format]) {
            if (i>240 && i<250) {
                NSBeginAlertSheet(@"Check the loop", @"Delete", nil, @"Cancel", window, self, @selector(alertEnd:returnCode:cInfo:), NULL, nil, @"format===%@,%d",format);
            }
        }
   }
}
```

}

Above methods is working fine if I run the project by Code (X code), but getting issue if I run by build. I am importing songs from iTunes library.xml, after that I am storing into `NSArrayController`. Here in this method I am trying to fetch artwork images but if I run by build I am getting around 250 images out of 400.

Answer (score 0):

Without the code of alertEnd:returnCode:cInfo: it's hard to tell, but it generally appears like something in that function is killing the for loop.

What exactly are you trying to achieve with:

```
            if (i>240 && i<250)
```

Can you post the code for the 'alertEnd:returnCode:cInfo'. Also it would probably be easier to read if you used a __block for alert sheets. If the alertEnd:returnCode:cInfo isn't referred to more than once, I'd keep it as a block. If you reuse the code within alertEnd:returnCode:cInfo then promote it to it's own void/function.

Comment: actually i am getting around 248 out of 400 artwork images when i run by build. So for the debugging purpose i added NSBeginAlertSheet to find out the issue. am not doing anything with selector.

Answer (score 0):

some possibilities:

- you are importing/reading a different "iTunes library.xml" file that was created with a smaller set of itunes files. and maybe that filename is set in the xcode arguments???
- [noOfSongs count] has an inconsistent value, because objects are removed from noOfSongs

try :

```
NSInteger *cntSongs = [[mySongsArray content] count];
for (int i=0; i< cntSongs; i++) {
```

rather than the current:

```
NSArray *noOfSongs = [mySongsArray content];
for (int i=0; i<[noOfSongs count]; i++) {
```

- mySongsArray is shadowed by another property of the same name. see -Wshadow.

Comment: Gade Rainbow: The path is correct and its working very fine in MAC OS X 10.8 and above. but in 10.7 if i run by build then only i am getting this issue, if i run using X-Code its working fine. Why i am getting this issue in 10.7 if i run by build...